# Is there a way to perform a procedure in netlogo knowing only it's name?

Tags: netlogo

I am developing a netlogo extension and I want to add a command where the user will tell me a list of procedures names that have no parameters.
Later I will perform this procedures but the only thing I will know is the name of the procedure that was passed to me before.

The command that the user will use to inform the name of the procedures is the following:

`qlearningextension:actions ["procedure1" "procedure2" "procedure3"]`

Later the extension will perform this procedures. I want to know if there is a way to get a procedure with only having it's name.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to change the syntax of your primitive from taking in a list of strings to taking in a repeatable number of anonymous commands.  You can do this by setting the syntax to `CommandType | RepeatableType`.  A good reference should be the [ControlFlow extension (`cf`)](https://github.com/NetLogo/ControlFlowExtension/blob/hexy/src/main/CFExtension.scala#L19-L40) which uses a similar technique to accept at least 1, but possibly many, boolean/command combinations for its variadic `cf:iflese` primitive.

The anonymous commands provided will be checked for correctness at compile time, meaning you won't have to rely on the extension user properly typing the name of the procedures or forgetting if they change a name.  The commands will also be easily executable by your extension prim at runtime, you won't have to "search" for the right procedure to execute (again, see the `cf` example).

Users of your extension will need to wrap your prim in parens when using the "more than 1" repeatable syntax: `(qlearningextension:actions [procedure1] [procedure2] [procedure3])`

Comment: If I get it right, by setting the Syntax this way: `override def getSyntax: Syntax = commandSyntax(right = List(RepeatableType))` I will be able to do this: `(qlearningextension:actions [procedure1] [procedure2] [procedure3])`.
Am I right?

Comment: It should be something like `commandSyntax(right = List(CommandType | RepeatableType))` which should mean "0 or more `CommandType` arguments".  That way you'll get compile-time checking that the arguments to the procedure are correctly set to anonymous commands.